# How to fit asymmetric Gaussian curve in python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I get a Gaussian curve it is asymmetric but I need to fit,
How can I achieve this in the python, I am not able to fit the graph.

[image]

Below is the code. I try to read it from the excel file in which `x` and `y` values are in two different sheets.
The Gaussian function worked fine for me, I need to make it fit

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


#def gaussian(x, x0, sigma, height):
    #return height * np.exp(- 0.5 * (x - x0) ** 2 / sigma ** 2)

def asymGaussian(x, p):
    amp = (p[0] / (p[2] * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
    spread = np.exp((-(x - p[1]) ** 2.0) / (2 * p[2] ** 2.0))
    skew = (1 + erf((p[3] * (x - p[1])) / (p[2] * np.sqrt(2))))
    return amp * spread * skew

def residuals(p, y, x):
    return y - asymGaussian(x, p)



# This is just to enlarge the fontsize in the plot
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'large',
          'axes.labelsize': 'x-large',
          'axes.titlesize': 'x-large',
          'xtick.labelsize': 'x-large',
          'ytick.labelsize': 'x-large'}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
filename = "Au intensity.xlsx"

# Read all data
var = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=0).dropna()

# Read Binding energies from column E of Sheet 2
BEs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=1, header=None)

# Rename row headers with binding energies
var.index = BEs.values.reshape(var.shape[0])

# Read Angles from column A of Sheet 3
angles = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=2, header=None)

# Rename column headers with angles
var.columns = angles.values.reshape(var.shape[1])
angle_range = 6  # Change this if you want to sum over a different range of angles
                     
# Be sure that each range corresponds more or less to the same number of columns
vertical_shift = 250  # Change this if you want to plot the curves more or less distant (vertically)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
for i in range(0, int(var.columns.max())+1, angle_range):
    df = var[var.columns[((var.columns>=i) & (var.columns<i+angle_range))]]
    y = df.sum(axis=1).values.astype(float)
    initials = [df.index, max(y), 2206, 1.5]
    #p,pcov=curve_fit(
        asymGaussian(df.index, p),
        df.index, y, p0=[2204, 0.8, max(y)]
    )
    #y_gaussian=gaussian(df.index, p[0],p[1],p[2])
    cnsts = leastsq(
    residuals, 
    initials, 
    args=(
            y, # y value
            df.index  # x value
        )
    )[0]
    y1 = asymGaussian(df.index, cnsts)
    #y = y / max(y)   # This is to normalize each plot to 1
    ax.plot(
        df.index,
        y + i * vertical_shift,
        label="%.d"%i + "°-%.d"%(i + angle_range) + "°"
    )
    ax.plot(df.index, y1 + i*vertical_shift)
    #ax.plot(df.index, y_gaussian + i * vertical_shift)
    print("Range of angles:", i, i+angle_range, "Number of columns:", df.shape[1])
    #print(p)
ax.set_xlim(max(df.index), min(df.index))
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_xlabel("Binding energy (eV)")
ax.set_ylabel("Intensity (a.u.)")
#ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a skewed Gaussian, but a Gaussian with a smooth-step background.

Comment: ...so maybe you try fitting something like `gauss + k *( 1 - t ( x - s ) / sqrt( 1 + t**2 (x -s)**2 )  )`